# Is Silverlight 5 going to have transport security for net.tcp WCF services?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

Does anyone know, one way or the other, whether Siverlight 5 will support security for net.tcp service bindings?

I can't find any mention of it listed in the Silverlight 5 Beta features (though I haven't tried the Beta).

Appreciate any info.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is currently not planned for Silverlight 5. The list of planned features for SL5 (including those which are not in the beta features) can be found at http://i1.silverlight.net/content/downloads/silverlight_5_beta_features.pdf?cdn_id=1.